# String should not start with ! or = Regex Expression

Tags: c#, regex, asp.net-mvc

I am looking for a regex which doesn't allow string to be started with either '!' or '='. Here is my code at the moment in which I have only added the code for '=' which doesn't work.

```
[RegularExpression("^(?!=)", ErrorMessageResourceName="Error_StringStartWith",      ErrorMessageResourceType= typeof(CommonStrings))]
public String FirstName { get; set; }
```

Comment: Try `[RegularExpression("^[^!=]", ErrorMessageResourceName="Error_StringStartWith",      ErrorMessageResourceType= typeof(CommonStrings))]
`

Comment: You need to add `.*` (followed by 0 or more characters) i.e. `^(?!=).*`

Comment: `(?!)` is negative look ahead construct, so you need to combine the suggestions from @MarcinJuraszek and @StephenMuecke

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're looking for `(?![!=]).*`

```
(?!                       // Negative lookahead
    [!=]                  // Match either ! or = literal
)
.*                            // Match any token zero to unlimited times
```

@Rawling pointed out to me that it is not necessary to assert the beginning of the string, so I've removed that.

Comment: @xanatos A valid input like `FooTheBar` wouldn't match without that quantifier.

Comment: @jdphenix I'm not sure whether `RegularExpressionAttribute` implicitly adds the `^` and `$` anchors - [these examples](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.regularexpressionattribute) suggest it doesn't - so either the `.*` is unnecessary or the `^` is.

Comment: @Rawling I wasn't sure, so I created a sample MVC project using both regexes. It behaved as I described when I removed the `.*` quantifier. I'll admit I'm not sure about the `^` assertion though.

Comment: @jdphenix Fair enough, if you've tried it out I can't really argue :p Edit: looking in the [reference source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations/R/55793ed332d816a5.html), the attribute checks `(m.Success && m.Index == 0 && m.Length == stringValue.Length)` so you're right, the `.*` is required and the `^` and `$` are not.